# conditions for $A +B$ to be semi-definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite real matrix, and $B$ is symmetric and real matrix with $B_{ii}>0$.   Are there conditions on $\sup_{j}|B_{ij}|$ that can guarantee $A+B$ is semi-definite.   Obviously $\sup_{j}|B_{ij}|=0$ for all $i$ works.   Also if $B$ is diagonally dominate then $A+B$ is positive semi-definite.   Are there any other conditions?

Comment: $A$ is positive definite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite, then $A+B$ is also positive semidefinite.  On the other hand, if all you know about $A$ is that it is positive semidefinite, then the only way to ensure $A+B$ is positive semidefinite is to have $B$ be positive semidefinite (after all, $A$ could be $0$, or it could be $B$).

EDIT: If $A$ is positive definite with minimum eigenvalue $\lambda$, then what you want to ensure is that $x^T B x \ge -\lambda x^T x$ for all $x$.  If $\epsilon = \sup_{j \ne i} |B_{ij}|$ we have
$$x^T B x \ge \sum_i \sum_{j \ne i} x_i B_{ij} x_j \ge - \epsilon \left(\sum_i |x_i|\right)^2 \ge - n \epsilon x^T x $$ 
so it suffices that $\epsilon \le \lambda/n$.

Comment: Yes.   I should re-write the question to have A strictly positive definite